# проблема с переадресацией (бесконечная)

Tags: php

Казалось бы, обычный код. Если есть айди в таблице, кидаем на страницу бан и никуда больше не пускаем. Но браузер пишет, что много цикличных переадресаций и не может отобразить страницу :(

```
if (DB::$dbs->querySingle("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `banlist` WHERE `id_users_ban` = '".App::user()->id."' AND `time` > '".time()."' LIMIT 1")){
    header ('location: /ban.php');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: в  /ban.php тоже запрос к базе ? или какой нить локашин ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']!='/ban.php' && DB::$dbs->querySingle("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `banlist` WHERE `id_users_ban` = '".App::user()->id."' AND `time` > '".time()."' LIMIT 1")){
    header ('location: /talk/');
}
```

решено.